# LINQ to remove rows from datatable whose values in list<string>

Tags: c#, linq

I have datatable with two columns: id, title.
And i need to remove from the table the rows whose 'title' column values are included in the list.
Think the most correct way to do this is with linq to datatable, but dont know how.
Help me please build linq query. 
Or can there be another effective way? More than 100k rows in this table.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Remove or turn rows invisible? Also please use more linebreaks in your question.

Comment: i need to remove this rows

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use:

```
List<DataRow> rowsToRemove = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => list.Contains(r.Field<string>("title")))
    .ToList();

rowsToRemove.ForEach(table.Rows.Remove);
```

Comment: @eXcelsior when it works please mark the answer as the right answer.

Comment: This code reads ALL ROWS in table into client.

Comment: @ornic: I think you have overlooked that this is not Linq-To-Entities or Linq-To-Sql but [Linq-To-DataTable/Linq-To-DataSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/queries-in-linq-to-dataset). `DataSets` or `DataTables` are in-memory collections. [`AsEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable?view=net-6.0) is an extension method that enables to use LINQ on the old non-generic `DataTable` class.